# Replace URL whether http or https

Tags: javascript, str-replace

I have a form that takes user inputted url and replaces an old url with a new one. The url the user will input is in this format:
https://oldproxy.server.url.edu/login?url=https://destinationurl.com. OR http://oldproxy.server.url.edu/login?url=https://destinationurl.com

My script successfully finds all instances when the user starts with http, but if they start with https it fails. How can I include to check for http or https?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <script language="javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[// ><!--
    function makeLink() {
      var oin = document.frm.intext;
      var oout = document.frm.outtext;
      var intxt = oin.value;
      if (intxt.length == 0) {
        oin.focus();
        alert("No URL entered!");
      } else {
        //no
        var prep = "https://newproxy.server.url.edu";
        //no
        var rc = intxt.indexOf('.newproxy.server.url.edu/')
        var rd = intxt.indexOf('.newproxy.server.url.edu')
        var wellFormedHttp = intxt.indexOf('http://')
        var wellFormedHttps = intxt.indexOf('https://')
        if (wellFormedHttp == '0' || wellFormedHttps == '0') {
          //alert("Matched http://"+wellFormed); 
          //} 
          if (rc == -1) {
            if (rd == -1) {
              intxt = intxt.replace(/http:\/\/oldproxy.server.url.edu/g, "")
              oout.value = prep + intxt;
              oout.focus();
              oout.select();
            } else {
              alert("dont need to replace");
              intxt = intxt.replace(/.newproxy.server.url.edu/g, "")
              oout.value = prep + intxt;
              oin.focus();
              oin.select();
            }
          } else {
            alert("duplicate");
            oout.value = "";
            oin.focus();
            oin.select();
          }
        } else {
          alert("The URL source URL doesn't start with http:// or https:// or contains multiple entries, please enter a valid URL like https://someaddress.com");
          oout.value = "";
          oin.focus();
          oin.select();
        }
      }

    }

    //--><!]]>
  </script>
  <form name="frm" id="frm">
    <h3>1. Copy and paste your source URL here:</h3>
    <p><textarea aria-label="Source URL" cols="60" name="intext" rows="5"></textarea><br />
    </p>
    <h3>2. Click this:</h3>
    <p><input onclick="makeLink();" type="button" class="btn" value="CONVERT LINK" /><br />
    </p>
    <h3>3. Copy, use, and share the resulting link</h3>
    <p><textarea aria-label="Resulting Link" cols="60" name="outtext" rows="5" id="myInput"></textarea></p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OT: please consider learning "how to indent code"

Comment: should parse it with [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and/or change params with [searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams), not replace

Comment: Could you please add the exact input and their respected outputs?

Comment: They will input:` http://oldproxy.server.url.edu/login?url=https://destinationurl.com` or `https://oldproxy.server.url.edu/login?url=https://destinationurl.com`
-expected output is:
`https or http://newproxyserver.url.edu/login?url=whatever they inputted above`(destinationurl.com)

Comment: sorry my comment above not formatted right: they will input http or https and then specifically oldproxy.server.url.edu. the output should be https:// always so output is`https://newserver/login?url=destination.url.com

Comment: so take their input for oldproxy.server.url.edu (whether http or https) and replace that with new newproxyserver , and append their inputted destination url

Comment: re formatting- yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

The below example matches the whole url with regular expression and replaces the catching group with url with the new url, starting with `https://`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <script language="javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[// ><!--
    function makeLink() {
      var oin = document.frm.intext;
      var oout = document.frm.outtext;
      var intxt = oin.value;
      
      if (intxt.length == 0) {
        oin.focus();
        alert("No URL entered!");
      } else {
        var new_url = "newproxyserver.url.edu";
        document.frm.outtext.value = intxt.replaceAll(/(https?:\/\/)(.+?)(\/.+)/gi, `https://${new_url}$3`);
      }

    }

    //--><!]]>
  </script>
  <form name="frm" id="frm">
    <h3>1. Copy and paste your source URL here:</h3>
    <p><textarea aria-label="Source URL" cols="60" name="intext" rows="5"></textarea><br />
    </p>
    <h3>2. Click this:</h3>
    <p><input onclick="makeLink();" type="button" class="btn" value="CONVERT LINK" /><br />
    </p>
    <h3>3. Copy, use, and share the resulting link</h3>
    <p><textarea aria-label="Resulting Link" cols="60" name="outtext" rows="5" id="myInput"></textarea></p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```